# How to set yOrient property to right in ngx-chart?

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I use vertical-bar-chart in my project. It seems that it's [possible](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/347#issuecomment-301186920) to move `Yaxis` to the `right` in the ngx-chart. But how it can be done?
I tried to do it with help of css transform, but it is not a good solution and y axis moves off after resizing window.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the link you provided, the yOrient property is not exposed.  What ngx-charts allow you to do is create custom charts.  I'd recommend creating a custom chart (see https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/combo-chart).  What I'd do is simply duplicate the type of chart you're trying to make with an additional y axis.  At this point you can set the yOrient property.

EDIT:
I've needed to make some very complex charts and ngx-charts just hasn't cut it for me...  So I made my own.  GitHub: https://github.com/yarz-tech/ng-charts.  Demo:https://yarz-tech.github.io/ng-charts/  Hopefully this helps you out.